# SQL function return many fields

Tags: sql, oracle, return

I am writing an SQL function, which is returning the result of three fields of select, How should I return the three detected values?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ATK_SMSPHONE(POLICY IN VARCHAR2, INSUREDNUMBER IN NUMBER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS
VPHONE VARCHAR2(100);
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(30);
LASTNAME VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
SELECT ADRESSE_ADHERANT, PRENOM_ADHERANT, NOM_ADHERANT INTO VPHONE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM ADHERANT WHERE POLICE = POLICY
AND NUMERO_ADHERANT = INSUREDNUMBER
AND ROLE_MEMBRE = 0;
RETURN VPHONE,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
RETURN ''; 
 END; 
 /
```

I have tried many options but in vain, sorry but i forgot how to use SQL :/

Comment: Is this SQL Server or Oracle? Also, how will this function be called? What is its purpose? If you're passing the dataset returned by the select statement back to a calling procedure, then potentially you're looking at needing to return a ref cursor.

Comment: It is Oracle, It is supposed to be called by other request, it is supposed to give three fields, but the problem in the return, how to return three values not one

Comment: "other request" - what do you mean by that? Is it another PL/SQL procedure? A SQL statement? A .NET procedure? Something else? Please edit your question to supply more information on how the result from this function will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
create or replace type threeValues as object ( VPHONE VARCHAR2(100),
                                               FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(30),
                                               LASTNAME VARCHAR2(30)
                                             )
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ATK_SMSPHONE(POLICY IN VARCHAR2, INSUREDNUMBER IN NUMBER)
    RETURN threeValues IS
    retVal                                  threeValues;
BEGIN
    SELECT threeValues(
                       '99',
                       'aa',
                       'bb'
                      )
      INTO retVal
      FROM DUAL;
    return retVal;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        RETURN null;
END;
/
```

The call:

```
SQL> select ATK_SMSPHONE('', '').VPHONE from dual;

ATK_SMSPHONE('','').VPHONE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
99

SQL> select ATK_SMSPHONE('', '') from dual;

ATK_SMSPHONE('','')(VPHONE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
THREEVALUES('99', 'aa', 'bb')
```